# Alexa Remainder API (REST API) - Invalid bearer token

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to send the Alert/Remainder via POSTMan to my skill.

**Option 1:** Authentication token API  with Scope "**alexa:skill_messaging**"

```
POST /auth/o2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.amazon.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2ae7afa3-c3f8-493f-b6e3-2db1e44e3a17,a4e45e8e-d0eb-4b3f-a612-e7d1959fdbe6
Host: api.amazon.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 236
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=******************&client_secret=***********17a4f7b348982bdb4&scope=alexa%3Askill_messaging
```

Screenshote:
[image]

**option 2:**  Authentication token API  with Scope **"alexa::alerts:reminders:skill:readwrite"**

```
POST /auth/o2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.amazon.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2ae7afa3-c3f8-493f-b6e3-2db1e44e3a17,c6765f77-6e35-419f-b614-780dae20ad4e
Host: api.amazon.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 236
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=**************************&client_secret=************************&scope=alexa%3A%3Aalerts%3Areminders%3Askill%3Areadwrite
```

[image]

**Step 2:**  Submitting the Alert request using token generated by Scope **"alexa:skill_messaging"**  getting **Invalide Bearer token**

[image]

Let me know if I am missing anything and also where can find different scope for Alexa Authenictaion Token API

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,

*"That's a limitation of the Reminders API - you need to use the in-session access token to create reminders. You can run GET, UPDATE and DELETE operations out of session as well, so check [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html#in-session-and-out-of-session-behavior-for-alexa-reminders-api) out for more information."*

Only speaking with the device is possible get in-session access token to create reminders.

Out-session - Get reminders created by the skill (Skill Messaging API):

```js
    const IncomingMessageHandler = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
            return request.type === 'Messaging.MessageReceived'
        },
        async handle(handlerInput) {
            const { requestEnvelope, context } = handlerInput;
            console.log(`Message content: ${JSON.stringify(requestEnvelope.request.message)}`);

            try {
              const client = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getReminderManagementServiceClient();
              const remindersResponse = await client.getReminders();
              console.log(JSON.stringify(remindersResponse));
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(`error message: ${error.message}`);
              console.log(`error stack: ${error.stack}`);
              console.log(`error status code: ${error.statusCode}`);
              console.log(`error response: ${error.response}`);
            }

            context.succeed();
        }
    }
```

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html#in-session-and-out-of-session-behavior-for-alexa-reminders-api

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/196445/reminders-can-only-be-created-in-session.html#answer-196860

https://developer.amazon.com/pt-BR/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html